# make_Weka_classifier("weka/classifiers/bayes/naiveBayes") and J48 not working on my R?

Tags: r, naivebayes, rweka, j48

I tried googling around but can't find any answer to this problem.

Currently trying to use Naive Bayes on R using Weka but am getting this error and I also tried using J48 to visualize a decision tree but that's not working out either.

> Error in make_Weka_classifier("weka/classifiers/bayes/NaiveBayes") : could not find function "make_Weka_classifier" for the Naive Bayes and Error in J48(pep ~ var1 + var2 + var3, data=dataset) : could not find function "J48"

Not sure what's wrong but I did these 2 lines at the start of my code:

```r
install.packages("RWeka")
library(RWeka)
```

Hope I could get some help on this, thanks!

Comment: Hello @qwerty123. Welcome on SO! Please add all the relevant code in your question. Cheers

Comment: When you run `library(RWeka)` do you get any messages?